# QGIS - Point sampling tool

Tags: qgis, plugins

I am using QGIS version 2.18 (la palma), and I'd like to create a vector layer as point and save it as CSV file, but I can't find that option on my QGIS.
[image]

Comment: If you want an answer to your question, be more precise about what you'd like to do. Point sampling tool does collect "polygon attributes and raster values from multiple layers at specified sampling points" (see plugin's description) - thus if you already have a points-layer. If you just want to create a points- (vector) layer, that's something completely different (menu layer > create new vector layer). So state what exactly you intend to do, otherwise it will not be possible to guess what want to do. By the way: there are newer long-term-releases for QGIS

Answer (score 3):

The option to save data as CSV directly from Point Sampling Tool was added in QGIS 3.x. It was not exist in QGIS 2.x. Here is the [changelog](https://github.com/borysiasty/pointsamplingtool/blob/master/CHANGELOG) directly from the plugin developer, and I will quote the following:

> ver 0.5 Updated for **QGIS 3.0**. Default output format is now GeoPackage.
>   **Optionally also CSV** and SHP. Allow appending to existing GeoPackags
>   and overwriting other files.

The answer is you need to use QGIS 3.4 Long Term Release (LTR) or the latest 3.10 to have the option to save the output from Point Sampling Tool into CSV directly.